# AngularJS ng-repeat with given number of loops from input form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

First of all I've got an ng-model where you select a number of entries from a html number input type, then I want to use this selection to produce a loop with ng-repeat and create other input forms.

The code starts like this:

```
<div data-ng-app="myapp" data-ng-init="entries=0" class="form-group" style="width: 300px;height: 100px;">
        <label for="input_nr">Input:</label>
        <input type="number" ng-model="entries" class="form-control" id="input_nr" min="0" step="1" value="0">
        </br>            
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="{{$entries}}"><span>hello</span></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

My $scope.myNumber should be equal to the value stored in "entries" from the ng-model.
Please give me some advices.

I attach a JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/CasianS/vaf44jwz/ .

So if I select 9 (exemple) I want to display 9 times "hello".

Comment: Do you want to show only no. of items in entries?

Comment: If so, use `limitTo` filter https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

Comment: "entries" should represent the number of loops in my next ng-repeat

Comment: Your code looks messy, why are you have two `ng-app` directives used in your HTML

Comment: You have right. I changed the code and I attached a JsFiddle. Please take a look now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:  Seeing the fiddle the OP just provided, I have a better understanding of the situation.  What you want is html something like this:

```
<h3>ng-repeat example</h3>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<label for="input_nr">Input:</label>
<input type="number" ng-model="entries" ng-change="upateEntries()" class="form-control" id="input_nr" min="0" step="1" value="0">
</br>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

And the Javascript something like this:

```
var m = 'hello'

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.entries = 0;
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.upateEntries = function () {
        $scope.items = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.entries; i++) {
            $scope.items.push(m);
        }
    }
}
```

(more or less).  As noted in the comments, ng-repeat is a lot like a foreach loop.  It's just going to iterate over an object or an array. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

This approach sets up a method that fires when the input changes and adds the required item to an array a specified number of times, and the ng-repeat iterates over that item.  Note that you can't have duplicates in an ng-repeat, so you have to add the track by $index statement if you go use a strategy like this.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Cavanaghacea/19x5mmum/12/

//OLD ANSWER BELOW

You should be able to use a limitTo: filter - like this:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
      <div ng-controller="ctrlParent">
          <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="entries" | limitTo:$scope.myNumber><span>{{$index+1}}</span></li>
          </ul>

      </div>
</div>


    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
        app.controller('ctrlParent',function($scope){
            $scope.myNumber = 3;
            $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
                return new Array(num);   
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Actually, after looking at the fiddle you provided, I think I misunderstood what you wanted to do.  It looks like you want 'hello' repeated as many times as the number specified in the input.  I think that you're misunderstanding how ng-repeat works.

Comment: Exactly! That was the idea, to use ng-repeat like a for loop...but you have right, I completely thought wrong. So is there any other posibility to creat this kind of result with angular?

Comment: certainly, but the approach would be a little bit different.  ng-repeat will iterate over an object.  You can limit the number of iterations with the | limitTo filter.  One approach would be to have a method on your scope that was triggered when the input changes, which basically creates an object or array with 'hello' repeated the correct number of times.  For example, if you selected '3' then your array would look like `[hello, hello, hello]`.  If your array was called 'text', for instance, your ng-repeat would look something like `<li ng-repeat="item in text">{{item}}</li>`

Comment: Your suggestion is great! I am going to search some more info on the net and the final idea will be to create an array of numbers (if I select 3, the array will be [1,2,3] and then I will be able to use the ng-repeat to creat a number of new input forms so many times as the array.lenght. Thanks a lot!

Comment: ok, here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Cavanaghacea/19x5mmum/12/  - I'll edit the answer to show the new code.

Comment: Happy to help @CasianS!  If you end up using an approach like this, would you mind accepting this answer?  Thanks!

Comment: Sure! Thanks a lot for your help ;)